# GridBagLayout not changing for each row

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout

I want the first row of three components to be spaced out with weights of 1,0.5,0.5. So the first component should be twice as long as the others. In the second row I want all three components to be of weight 0.5 (same length). `GridBagLayout` is behaving weird.

```
public class Main extends JFrame{

public Main() {
        super();

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Label 1");
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        this.add(label, c);

        JLabel label2= new JLabel("Label 2");
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        label2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        this.add(label2, c);

        JLabel label3= new JLabel("Label 3");
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        label3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        this.add(label3, c);

        JLabel label4 = new JLabel("1");
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        label4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        this.add(label4, c);

        JLabel label5= new JLabel("2");
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        label5.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        this.add(label5, c);

        JLabel label6= new JLabel("3");
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        label6.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        this.add(label6, c);


        this.setSize(900,900);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Comment: GridBagLayout might not be the best layout for this type of gui, and you might need to use other layouts such as MigLayout.

Comment: And the code is working exactly as expected

Comment: For me the second row looks exactly the same as the first row

Comment: @a.kumar Sorry, yes, that's what I mean by "expected", based on the code you've provided, the code is doing exactly what I would expect, not what you want ;)

Comment: Do you know how i would get it to do what i want? because i changed the weight x each time i added a component...Does adding a component with a constraint update the component after the constraint has changed or something? this is weird

Comment: You have to rememeber, `GridBagLayout`, is just a fancy pancy "grid", so components are still added in rows/columns, just with a lot more configurability

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495188/gridbaglayout-erratic-resizing-and-displaying .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want the first row of three components to be spaced out with weights of 1,0.5,0.5.

The "weights" are only used when the frame is resized. That is the components are originally display at their preferred size. Then when you increase the space in the frame the extra space is allocated in the ratio you specified.

If you want to maintain the ratio at all times then you also need to create your components with a preferred size in that ratio.

Or you might be able to use the [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/). It was designed to avoid this problem and allow you to specify relative sizes for each component. You would obviously need to create multiple panels for each row.

Comment: then, how come the components are not all the same size (because i never assigned a preferred size)? If it just assumed the preferred size because of the weights, then how come the second row isn't different?

Comment: Every component determines its own preferred size based on the properties of the components. Given that the text is different, the preferred size will be different.  Also because you have a grid the layout has to set the size for each column of the grid. You can't have different widths for column 1 on row2 and row2. So in your simple example the width of each column will be determined by the first row, since that row contains the largest components.

Comment: @a.kumar The preferredSize comes from the text and the icon (and other) properties of the label, `weightx` and `weighty` define how the leftover space is distributed to the components

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that GridBagLayout doesn't allow different width size for each component in a column, thanks!

Comment: Components can still be displayed at a different size in a column. That is unless you use the "fill" property a component will be displayed at its preferred size. However the maximum width of the column is determined by the largest component in the column. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) it explains how each constraint works.

Comment: `Oh, I didn't know that GridBagLayout doesn't allow...` - so then the question is answered?